# Count of arrays having consecutive element with different values

Tags: combinations, permutation

Given two positive integers  **n** ,  **m** . The task is to count the number of different array that can be formed of size  **n** such that each element is between **1** to **m** and two consecutive element are different. Also, the first and last elements of each array should be same.

```
I/p                          O/p
3   3        -->             6
3   4        -->            12
4   4        -->            24
```

This is what I have got

If `n == 3`  output is `m * (m - 1)`
If `n != 3` output is `m * ((m - 1)^(n - 3)) * (2 * m - 3)`

**Explanation**

```
At first place there are m choices.
From 2nd to (n - 2) places there is there  are (m - 1) choices. 
For (n - 1) place there are 2 cases: 
    1st is if (n - 2) and nth place are same then (m - 1) choices
    2nd is if (n - 2) and nth place are not same then (m - 2) choices

So total (2 * m - 3) choices.
```

If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: It is worth to show your own thoughts and tryouts

Comment: From the constraints it is quite clear that you need to derive a formula for it. Math question. Take some values of M, N and show some analysis.